# 503 Service Unavailable after 60 seconds Apache Symfony (in certain features only)

Tags: php, apache, fpm

I currently face an issue in a **Symfony 3.4** application, in one of its features which loads history of some data (a lot of data actually which dates from 2017).

When trying to access the history feature, the GET http request keeps loading for **60 seconds** exactly, then a **503 service unavailable** shows up, same issue happens in other features that loads big number of data.

Checked the logs, application logs & server (apache) logs, only apache **logs** shows 503 code with no details.

I suspected the **php.ini** configuration, and changed values of **max_execution_time** to -1 and **memory_limit** to 2048M, but still the GET http request terminates after **60 seconds exactly.**

I also use **php-fpm** and checked the **www.conf** and it doesn't have anything that overrides the values of **php.ini**, I even added **request_terminate_timeout** = 600s to only see if the value will be taken into consideration but still the same issue, GET http request of the history terminates exactly after 60 seconds of loading (waiting).

I make sure to restart php-fpm & httpd (apache) after the changes in the configuration file.

Database server is working fine, since I can access other data in other features.

Expected behaviour:

I expected at least the GET http request to keep loading for more than 60 seconds, other than that it means I still didn't find the correct param

Logs from ssl_access_log:
ip - - date "GET /p/a/h HTTP/1.1" 503 299

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Solution was to specifically add TimeOut 600 to httpd.conf configuration file of apache server.
Even if the file doesn't have TimeOut, it's by default applied as TimeOut 60 which results in a GET http request to break after 60 seconds of waiting.
The solution was suggested in this link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/769975/503-service-unavailable-after-60-seconds-apache-symfony-in-certain-features-onl